# Modular multiplication

Tags: rust

Given `a`, `b` and `m`, all of type `u64` (or `u128`), I want to calculate `(a * b) % m`. However, `a` and `b` may be large, so an overflow may occur.

While I could cast them to `BigUInt`, multiply them and then cast the result back, this seems a bit unelegant to me. (Since the casting to `BigUInt` is theoretically unnecessary.)

I also found the [modular arithmetic](https://docs.rs/modular_arithmetic/latest/modular_arithmetic/index.html) crate, but it seems to be unmaintained, undocumented and the multiplication is *very* slow in case of an overflow. Also, there is the [modular](https://docs.rs/modular/1.0.0/modular/) crate, but there an overflow can occur.

So, is there a more elegant way to do modular multiplication in Rust?

Comment: I think as @JeremyMeadows points out, you might have to implement your own algorithm.
I have an idea, though. It's based aroud the fact that `(x + a) % m == (x - (m - a)) % m`. By that, you can flip `a` to be always smaller than `m/2`. With this you can calculate the "offset" that happens if you add one `a` to a number. Then, we need to figure out how to add two of those offsets together without an overflow. If we can do that, we can split `b` down into its powers of two, figure out the offset for each power of two is, and add all of them together.

Comment: The solution in the duplicate is much faster than what I proposed, I think.

Answer (score 2):

If `m * m` is small enough to not overflow, you can use `(a % m) * (b % m) % m` to keep your multiplicands smaller, and it produces the same result as `a * b % m` because of neat modular properties.

Comment: That's correct, but in my case `m` is also large (which I admittedly did not write in the question), so `(a % m) * (b % m)` might still overflow.

Comment: @JakobW. if that's the case, you may have to implement your own modular multiplication function which keeps the values small enough

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there a more elegant way to do modular multiplication in Rust?

Unroll the multiplication to a sequence of modular additions?

Even if the additions can overflow (e.g. 190u8 + 170u8 mod 200u8), you can probably handle the case with `overflow_add` and adjust backwards.

Comment: That's exactly what his referenced [`modular arithmetic`](https://docs.rs/modular_arithmetic/latest/src/modular_arithmetic/arithmetic.rs.html#40-48) crate does, and it seems to be too slow for his usecase